# Can I use jsx for writing while transpiling it to simple HTML strings?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, jsx, template-literals

As I don't need any SPA functionality neither a framework like React/Preact or anything like that my dist code must not contain React's CreateElement or it's equivalents.

In fact I want to use it like this:

```js
const html = <div className="some-class">
  <span>something inside</span>
</div>
```

compiled to:

```js
var html = `<div class="some-class">
  <span>something inside</span>
</div>`
```

I checked a lot of babel plugins related to jsx, template-literals and jsx to html compilation but none worked for this usecase. Is it even possible or do I have to use template literals in my code?

Comment: Why don't you simply write the template literal in the first case (it differs by only two characters)? What features of JSX do you need?

Comment: "*my dist code must not contain React's CreateElement or it's equivalents.*" - why not? That would be the easiest solution, to have a `createElement` variant that returns html strings.

Comment: @Bergi In general I like the way how JSX is written. It's just more comfortable and the syntax highlighting is a nice feature you don't get in template literals.

for your second question: I just don't want the overhead created with these functions when they are not really necessary for my application

Comment: Well if you have dynamic JSX (with variables for attributes or children), you *need* such a function - and the overhead is rather small. Btw if you use a tagged template literal (`html\`<…>\``, e.g. [these](https://2ality.com/2015/01/template-strings-html.html) but there are more libraries), you usually even get syntax highlighting in them.

Comment: JSX is not HTML, so no, there's no way to do this without function calls of some kind. That being said, if you were willing to use a library, you can use HTM w/ (p)react. It's a tagged template lib that'll allow you to write JSX without the need for transpilation/a build step: https://github.com/developit/htm

Comment: Thats kind of a downer. I knew JSX is not HTML but I thought there could be a babel plugin or something that just translates it for me on the fly. 

Anyways thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score -2):

so you are trying to write JSX syntax(which looks much similar to HTML, well it's not) inside the .js file. JSX uses React.createElement to make the following component, which in terms require babel.

```
const html = <div className="some-class">
  <span>something inside</span>
</div>
```

so without using babel or any other such plugin, you cant do that.

Comment: I know it's not possible without a transpiler. I mentioned it in my question.